# Positioning in Slimbox

Tags: slimbox

Slimbox is working perfectly for me with one exception... my slideshows often open way to low. The positioning is effected by any scrolling already done on the page. Every time the page is scrolled a bit, the slideshow opens lower than it had previously for the same page. Scroll down the page much and the show can be completely out of sight.

lbCenter and lbBottomContainer in the CSS control the positioning, but I can't find how to adjust them accurately. The default is:

```
#lbCenter,
#lbBottomContainer {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9999;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

In an old thread here, I found suggestion for adding:

```
       top: 30px !important;
```

As long as !important is included, this does work but with a significant caveat; the caption is moved from below to above the image and covers some of it. *( And !Important doesn't seem like an ideal solution )*

How can I adjust the positioning of both while keeping the caption below the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was on me. My links included href="#" as some others required. The # caused the page to scroll to the top even as the slide show opened where the link was located.

```
<a href="#" onclick="show('homes')">
```

Eliminating the hash tag resolved it.